# Create a Linux Window Manager with Qt

Tags: linux, qt, window, xlib, window-managers

I wan't to display an extern X Application inside a Widget of a Qt program, even if the OS doesn't have a window manager.
Is it possible? If so, how can I do it? Or where should I begin?

Comment: If you have the window id(s) for the X app then you could make use of [QWidget::createWindowContainer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#createWindowContainer).

Comment: Thanks! I read that, but do you know if the performance would be good? Or if there is a better way to do it?

Comment: Depends on precisely what you mean by "performance".  I've used it a lot in the past and have never had anything I would consider a performance issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll give it a try :)

Comment: I'd start by taking a look at the existing open source window managers built in Qt. KDE is the obvious one, but the code base is pretty large. You might also check out LXQt.

Comment: Good idea, thanks for the tip :) I finally found the best way to go is to use Xlib libraries inside my app. [EXAMPLE](https://github.com/jichu4n/basic_wm)

Comment: Creating a window manager is very different  from embedding a single known window in a Qt widget. Decide which one you want.